# OpenVPN client connects but only loads SOME websites

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I set up OpenVPN server on a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS using OpenVZ. I can establish a connection to the VPN with a client. I can access some pages like Google and twitter but a lot of sites fail to load.

I added this to the iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source my-server-ip
```

My server.conf looks like this:

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert my-cert.crt
key my-key.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt


push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

Comment: Run a tcpdump or check if you get any log related to it. I doubt it mostly firewall issue. Check if you are accepting forward packet in your firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was editing iptables but never saving them (from fear of messing up previous rules).

By using this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I was able to test if my iptables were working without saving them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one DNS server first. It may be that one of the DNS servers isn't accepting incoming requests. In my setup I simply have the dhcp-option DNS pointing to my tun0 'inet addr:'. Run ifconfig on the server to find out what that address is. Something like 10.8.xx.xx

Answer (score 0):

It is likely fixed by a setting on the client and server config. See the [OpenVPN FAQ](http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/271-i-can-ping-through-the-tunnel-but-any-real-work-causes-it-to-lock-up-is-this-an-mtu-problem) question "I can ping through the tunnel, but any real work causes it to lock up. Is this an MTU problem?"